# Is there a list of status codes for Maytag Bravos Quiet Series 300?

Tags: washing-machine

The Maytag Bravos Quiet Series 300 washing machine has a display. It displays codes sometimes. Is there a list of status codes?

Comment: Here are some: http://laundry.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/maytag/mtw6700tq.html?p=21

Comment: Have you checked the Maytag website, or contacted technical support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Maytag Bravos® [Use & Care Guide (PDF)](https://www.maytag.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Use%20and%20Care%20Guide%20-%20W10330932.pdf)

> [image: Troubleshooting section of Use & Care Guide]

```
Code        Reason
LF          Washer is taking too long to fill
Ld          Washer is taking too long to drain
uL          Unbalanced load
oL          Overload
Sd          Suds detected
lid         Lid open
HC          Hot and cold supplies reversed
dL          Door/lid cannot lock
dU          Door/lid cannot unlock
Fd          Factory Default
F_ _        Fault code
```

If the machine is showing one of the fault codes, you'll have to contact Maytag. The list of fault codes is probably not publicly published, and is likely only available to Maytag service people.